# What is the easiest way to get MySQL's Archive Storage Engine working on CentOS 5.4

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

The Archive Storage Engine is not enabled by the default build of MySQL in CentOS/RHEL. I would like to enable it on our CentOS 5.4 server. My initial reaction was to modify the SPEC file for the SRPMS file, but [this](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=7511&forum=28&order=ASC&start=0) indicates that this might not be that easy. There's always the option to build from MySQL source, but I would prefer if possible to stay within the RPMS/Yum world.

Does anybody have a successful approach to this by using RPMS/SRPMS/Yum? Some patches which makes this work flawless with SRPMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build MySQL with changes to the SPECS file for MySQL and the Archive storage engine got enabled. Here's a detailed step on how to get this up and running:

Install yum-utils:

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
```

Include RedHat's SRPMS to the CentOS repos:

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/srpm.repo
```

Add the following repo configuration:

```
[rhel-src]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

I could not use `$releasever` in the URL, but had to set to `5Server`.

Download the SRPMS package:

```
 yumdownloader --source mysql-server
```

Set up build area for a non-root user:

```
 yum install rpm-build redhat-rpm-config
 mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
 echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros
 rpm -i mysql-server-5.0.xx.src.rpm
```

Install the required development tools:

```
 yum install gcc-c++ libtool gperf automake ncurses-devel readline-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
```

To find all the required libraries and tools, just try to the following command:

```
 cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
```

Modify the spec file:

```
 vi ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/mysql.spec
```

I added the following in the spec file (I wanted also to include the federated storage engine):

```
 %configure \
    ...
    --with-archive-storage-engine \
    --with-federated-storage-engine \
    ...
```

**Be aware:** This might have changed in MySQL 5.1 where `plugin` is used to specify storage engines.

In order to speed up the build process you should consider making this change:

```
 %{!?runselftest:%define runselftest 0}
```

Then run (as non-root user):

```
 cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
 rpmbuild -ba mysql.spec
```

You'll find the RPMs in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386`. Just install and run MySQL and you will get a MySQL version with archive storage engine enabled.